# Splitting vector ints into an int of those digits

Tags: c++, vector, int

Is there any way to do this? Basically I'm trying to take the process of putting digits of an int into a vector, but rather in reverse. Such that if vectorrandom values are 5, 6, 7... I can convert to an int that is of value "567". Is this even possible or doable?

Comment: Everything is doable, what did you try?

Comment: is this homework ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following function can be used to convert a vector of ints to a single integer number.

```
std::string Join(const std::vector<int>& intVector)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    for (const auto& element : intVector)
    {
        ss << element;      
    }
    return ss.str();
}
```

In above implementation range-based for loop is used as this feature is available in c++ 11. You can use normal for loop. 
To convert returned string value into an integer, you can use std::stoi algorithm (c++ 11) or atoi function.

Comment: Very inefficient solution. Why to use strings in the first place instead of just multiplying the previous result by 10 and adding the next digit to it?

Comment: I agree with you. But multiplying with 10 and adding the next digit to it, will fail if int vector is having elements which can not fit into integer datatype.

Comment: This should be checked in any case. It will fail with strings as well at the stage of converting to an int.

Comment: One more thing we need to do in case of multiplication and addition solution, is we need to check that each element in the vector is of length 1. Otherwise, the result will be incorrect.

Comment: The question speaks explicitly about vector of digits. If the input is not digits, it's invalid. Regardless of the method used.

Answer (score 0):

```
int Join(const std::vector<int>& intVector)
{
    unsigned long sum = 0;
    for (const int& i : intVector)
    {
        sum = (sum << 3) + (sum << 1); // sum*8 + sum*2 = sum*10;
        sum += i;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: I would imagine that the multiplication by 10 would be optimized by the compiler anyway. Also you accumulate the total in an `unsigned long` but return as an int.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is achievable, Just make sure that vector length is within the range of your datatype, for instance *int 64bit or int 32bit*.

Read more about [Data type ranges](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz.aspx)

**Pseudocode**

```
vector<int> vec{5, 6, 7};
int num = 0;
for(int x : vec)
    num = num*10 + x;
cout<<num; // 567
```

[**Ideone**](https://ideone.com/SKHu7W)